# 32 bit iso for mac to install on my macbook

Tags: software-installation, mac, downloads, iso

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/

I only see the x64 bit for mac is there anyway to get the 32 bit? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look here http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ or for a lighter system http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04.4/release/.
Have an easy install!